# Can any application broadcast Intent with action name "android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My application is registered for intent (`"android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"`) to handle wired headset key pressed using below code

```
<receiver
    android:name=".HeadsetEventReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Receiver `HeadsetEventReceiver` does some operation on receiving this Intent.

Now I have a sample application which broadcast an Intent with action as `"android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"` with valid KeyEvent object using below code.

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON")  ;
KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(System.currentTimeMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis(), KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 79, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHPAD);
newIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, event);
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(newIntent);
```

My application is receiving this Intent and processing this data as if it is actually broadcast due to headset key press.

My query is when any application try to send broadcast with native Intents(eg: `"android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"`) securityException is thrown. Why does it not apply for the above Intent(`"android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"`).

Comment: What api you are using??? Because it would not happen in api >= 15.

Comment: I am using api 21. My question is why securityException is not thrown when an application try to sendBroadcast with Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON")?. It is not related to listening to mediaButton event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Since **4.0 or greater** the **Android document** says that you have to use `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver` for registering the intent action. Without registering to `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver` you won't get broadcast message.

Below is the code which is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html)

```
AudioManager am = mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
...

// Start listening for button presses
am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver);
...

// Stop listening for button presses
am.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver);
```

So if you are using `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver` then you would get the broadcast else you won't.

Comment: I am using api 21. My question is why securityException is not thrown when an application try to sendBroadcast with Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON")?. It is not related to listening to mediaButton event listener.

Comment: It would not throw Exception because they have defined receivers to broadcast the same, so its not an issue for them. I guess so.